# How to Handle the pandas dataframe if the column name itself is a date in the Excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, date

How to select a specific column in the dataframe if the column name itself is a date, I've a column names in the excel  as 1-Jan-18 2-Jan-18 3-Jan-18
but in the dataframe  it is displaying something like below

> Index([            'Names',        'Unnamed: 1', 2018-01-01 00:00:00,
>          2018-01-02 00:00:00, 2018-01-03 00:00:00, 2018-01-04 00:00:00,
>          2018-01-05 00:00:00, 2018-01-06 00:00:00, 2018-01-07 00:00:00,
>          2018-01-08 00:00:00,
>          ...
>          2018-12-30 00:00:00, 2018-12-31 00:00:00,             'Leave',
>             'Optional ',               'XTR',              'Sick',
>            'Weekend ',   ' CompOff',           'B Shift',
>                    'C Shift'],
>         dtype='object', length=375)

I want to select only few specific date columns, how can I achieve this? Please advise.

```py
import pandas as pd
excel_file ='H:\TestingPy\Test.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name='LeaveTr',na_values="NaN")
#print(df.dtypes)
print(df.columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this,

```
df['columnName1', 'columnName2']= df['columnName1', 'columnName2'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%y')
```

Change `columnNames` to your actual columns which you want to change.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of the dates you want and then use them to filter the columns:

```py
    datelist = pd.to_datetime(['2018-01-01', '2018-01-03'])
    df.loc[:, df.columns.isin(datelist)]
```

This will return just the dates you specify.

If your dates are consecutive you could use:

```py
    df[pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-01-03')]
```

which will return those dates and everything between those dates.